# Problems with Sentry::authenticate() in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

When I try using the `sentry::authenticate()` it shows 'whoops, looks like something is wrong' in my browser. I don't know where this is coming from. 
Here's my route:

```
Route::post('login',function(){
   $credentials= array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password' =>Input::get('password'));
   $user=sentry::authenticate('$credentials,false);
});
```

But this doesn't work as soon as I click the login button

Comment: Set 'debug' equal to true in app/config/app.php to see the actual error message instead of that 'Whoops' screen.  Also, `Sentry` should be capitalized (`Sentry::authenticate()`), and you have an extra single quote inside your method call.  Though, once you turn debug on, it will be easier for you (and us) to track down the issue.

Comment: I just turned on the debug now this is the error it says:::      SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'syn.throttle' doesn't exist (SQL:select * from 'throttle' where 'user_id'= 1 and ('ip_address' = ::1 or 'ip_address' is null)limit 1)...       This is what it says but I don't have any table called throttle. So I don't know where it's seeing that from

Comment: That's what it is complaining about: you don't have a throttle table.  The throttle table should have been created as part of the install process for Sentry.  Sentry provides four migrations that setup the users, groups, users_groups, and throttle tables.  Did you run those migrations?

Comment: Four migrations?? I just did this in the migration.:  php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --create=users.... Is there something more I should do?

Comment: Yeah.  Sentry lays out the steps for installing their package into Laravel here: [https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#laravel-4](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#laravel-4).  They provide the migrations to use so that your database has all the tables and fields they need.  You can add fields to those tables later on, if you'd like, but you need to start off using their migrations.

Comment: No problem.  I have posted a quick summary answer to help any future searchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The issue was resolved in the comments.  Summary posted as answer here for future users.*

The main issue is that the migrations for the Sentry package had not been run.  Due to this, the throttle table did not exist, causing the code to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Basically i discovered that laravel 4 ships with its own migration tables and which needs to be run before the tables can be created in your database. 
Just run this below code:

php artisan migrate: --package cartalyst/sentry.

this will fix the problem for you.

Thanks to patricus.